# Google Analytics client id is not going into hidden field of my form

Tags: javascript

I am trying to capture Google client id from the cookie to hidden field of my form. I have been trying several solutions but none of them is working for me. Here is my landing page https://explore.labelbox.com/training-data-platforms-101

**Solution 1:**

```
<script>
  function getClientId (uaid) {
      try {
        var trackers = ga.getAll();
        var i, len;
        for (i = 0, len = trackers.length; i < len; i += 1) {
          if (trackers[i].get('trackingId') === uaid) {
            return trackers[i].get('clientId');
          }
        }
      } catch (e) {}
      return 'false';
    }
// By waiting for "onload", we give GA enough time to load up before trying to get the Client ID.
window.onload = function () {
    // Once the page has completely loaded, this next line finds the hidden field <input id="cid"> and sets its value to the CID. 
    document.getElementById("cid").value = getClientId('UA-XXXXX-X');
}
</script>
```

**Solution 2:**

```
<script>
  function getClientId (uaid) {
      try {
        var trackers = ga.getAll();
        var i, len;
        for (i = 0, len = trackers.length; i < len; i += 1) {
          if (trackers[i].get('trackingId') === uaid) {
            return trackers[i].get('clientId');
          }
        }
      } catch (e) {}
      return 'false';
    }
// By waiting for "onload", we give GA enough time to load up before trying to get the Client ID.
window.onload = function () {
    // Once the page has completely loaded, this next line finds the hidden field <input id="cid"> and sets its value to the CID. 
    document.getElementById("field-bfbc358e48e39a641df949bd3532ac90-8").value = getClientId('UA-XXXX-X');
}
</script>
```

Neither case is populating the value to the hidden field. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I take a quick look at your website, the reason you not getting anything is because `ga` object is `undefined`

[image]

So it never go to your for loop and it will return false. I think you didn't load the google analytics properly, you can follow the [official instruction](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs) how to load it, your script should run only after `ga` is loaded.

Comment: SO i tried that already but now i moved this script to GTM and fired after GA fires. But it seems like problem is still there. Any thoughts?